# How to add code for Google Analytics custom dimensions for the same call/hit made prior, with some custom dimensions ( which take time to calculate )

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, measurement-protocol

I have GA embedded on my website. 
I know I can send some custom dimensions, using

```
var d1 = "valueForD1";
ga('set', 'dimension1', d1);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**This is instantaneous.**

Other way to do this by Measurement Protocol API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).

with this

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
payload_data
```

**This hit is made(I make) when my server has completed some processing and calculated the custom dimension.**

But I need to add only "dimension1" to the original GA data already got sent (in normal GA execution) without ga('set','dimension1',d1).

My point here is that this custom dimension takes some time to get calculated on server end. How will I add this dimension to the GA normal hit?

Comment: Maybe you need to defer that first send, ask your server for that calculation and in the callback of that ajax request you call `ga('send',..)`.

Comment: What type of scope do you need? Session, hit , user?

Comment: Session scope .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If this is a session- or user scoped dimension it should be enough to send a hit (e.g. via the measurement protocol) with the same client id (within the session lifetime, for a session scoped dimension). Session scope and user scope retain only the last value per session/user in any case, so it's enough to add it once per session.

If this is a hit scoped dimension you are out of luck with a standard account. In a GA 360 account you can add dimensions and metrics to existing hits via [query time import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR : Send the hit on the call back function of the async call to send the event. As the example

Hi

The custom dimensions need to be attached to a hit (always to reach the platform).

The best way to work with async CD is to send this via a event, and setting the scope to Session or User Level. (this overwrite the previous hit data). The cons is that some users will not have the CD because you can send the hit of the PV and later the CD.

This is an example in code using the Ajax library to send the ip, (this is async too)

```js
 $.ajax({
    url:"https://api.ipify.org?format=json",  
    success:function(data) {
      console.log(data.ip);
      ga('send','event' , 'label', 'category' , {'dimension1' : data.ip}); 
    }
  });
```